# Add to clojure persistent vector map

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to figure out a way to add an object to a vector map.

```
(defstruct item :name)
(def itemList [])

(defn add-item [db & item] 
  (into db item))

(defn get-records[]
  (doseq [i (range 0 10 1)]  
   (add-records itemList  (struct item "test")
  ))
```

In the end of the loop I want `itemList` to contain 10 objects. Any help would very much appriciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clojure is a functional programming language and all of its main data structures are immutable and persistent. That also includes vector.

Your example needs managing a state. Clojure provides several abstractions for this, out of which, I think [atoms](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/atom) fit your use case best.

```
user=> (defrecord Item [name])
user.Item

user=> (def item-list (atom []))
#'user/item-list

user=> (defn add-item [db i] (swap! db #(conj % i)))
#'user/add-item

user=> (defn put-records [] 
         (doseq [i (range 10)] 
           (add-item item-list (Item. "test"))))
#'user/put-records

user=> (put-records)
nil

user=> item-list
#<Atom@4204: [#user.Item{:name "test"} #user.Item{:name "test"} #user.Item{:name "test"} #user.Item{:name "test"} #user.Item{:name "test"} #user.Item{:name "test"} #user.Item{:name "test"} #user.Item{:name "test"} #user.Item{:name "test"} #user.Item{:name "test"}]>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked really great :). Im quite new to Clojure , can you recommend any good tutorials to go ahead. Thank you

Comment: @user723056, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578837/comparing-clojure-books).

Answer (score 3):

missingfaktor's answer is right, if you really need to mutate something, but it would be much more normal to have:

```
(defstruct item :name)
(def itemList (for [i (range 10)] (struct item "test")))
```

in other words - create the list of objects with the contents.